# Send data from AJAX function to PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have an AJAX function that take data form a submit form and should pass varaibles to process.php

index.html is the main page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>League of Legends Straw Poll</title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                <h1 class="text-center">Game Straw Poll</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <!-- FORM -->
                        <form name="form" id="form" method="post">
                            <div class="row">   
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <!-- GAME -->
                                    <select class="form-control" id="game-group" name="game" onchange="ChangeBackground();">
                                        <option selected disabled>Select your Game...</option>
                                        <option value="League_of_Legends">League of Legends</option>
                                        <option value="Heartstone">Hearthstone</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <br>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <!-- QUESTION -->
                                    <div class="input-group" id="question-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="question" id="question" placeholder="Start typing your question...">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></i>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <br>
                            <div class="row">
                                <!-- OPTIONS -->
                                <div class="form-group form-group-options col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                    <div class="input-group input-group-option col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="options-group">
                                        <input type="text" name="option[]" id="option" class="form-control" placeholder="Options...">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon input-group-addon-remove">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <!-- CHOICE -->
                                    <div class="checkbox" id="choice-group">
                                        <label>
                                            <input type="checkbox" id="choice" name="choice" value="Yes">Allow multiple choice
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg pull-left" name="submit_button" id="submit_button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Create Poll</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Poll created</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Share it: <a href="http://gamepoll.net/<?php echo $rand_value; ?>">http://gamepoll.net/<?php echo $rand_value; ?></a></p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Chiudi</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Invia</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/addfield.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/changebackground.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='magic.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is magic.js file

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
$("#submit_button").click(function() 
{
    var game = $("#game-group:selected").val();
    var question = $("#question").val();
    var option = $("#option[]").val();
    var choice = $("#choice").val();

    if (game == '' || question == '' || option == '' || choice == '') 
    {
        alert("Insertion Failed Some Fields are Blank....!!");
    } 
    else 
    {
        // Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
        $.post("process.php", {
        game1: game,
        question1: question,
        option1: option,
        choice1: choice
        },
        function(data) 
        {
            alert(data);
            $('#form')[0].reset(); // To reset form fields
        });
    }
});
});
```

And this is process.php file

```
<?php
//Include configuration file
include('includes/config.php');

//Define variables
$game2=$_POST['game'];
$question2=$_POST['question'];
$option2=$_POST['option'];
$choice2=$_POST['choice'];

//Generate random number
$rand_value=rand();

//Create temporary folder
mkdir($rand_value);

//Copy page of Ask Poll
copy('page.php', $rand_value . '/page.php');
rename($rand_value . '/page.php', $rand_value . '/index.php');

//Add data into database
mysql_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_password) or die ("Errore di connessione!");
mysql_select_db($db_name) or die ("Impossibile selezionare database!");
$sql1="CREATE TABLE `" . $rand_value . "` (Question VARCHAR(200), Options VARCHAR(200), Choice INT(11))";
mysql_query($sql1) or die ("Impossibile eseguire la query!");

//Count number of Options available
$count=count($option);

for ($i=0; $i<($count-1); $i++)
{
    ${$sql . $i}="INSERT INTO `" . $rand_value . "` (Question, Options, Choice) VALUES ('$question2', '$option2[$i]', '$choice2')";
    mysql_query(${$sql . $i});
}   
?>
```

The problem is that the AJAX function doesn't pass data to process.php in fact i don't see any folder into my server or data saved into the database

Comment: change $game2=$_POST['game1'];
$question2=$_POST['question1'];
$option2=$_POST['option1'];
$choice2=$_POST['choice1'];

Answer (score 0):

change

`var option = $("#option[]").val();`

to

`var option = $("#option").val();`

you have assign `[]` operater in id selecter

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript property names dont match your php array keys:

```
{
    game1: game,
    question1: question,
    option1: option,
    choice1: choice
}

$game2=$_POST['game'];
$question2=$_POST['question'];
$option2=$_POST['option'];
$choice2=$_POST['choice'];
```

change one or the other, eg:

```
{
    game: game,
    question: question,
    option: option,
    choice: choice
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only issue I see is when calling the POST vars in your php you need to use the key names from your object. Not the variable names.

```
//Define variables
$game2=$_POST['game1'];
$question2=$_POST['question1'];
$option2=$_POST['option1'];
$choice2=$_POST['choice1'];
```

Hope this helps!